# When is the matrix $\begin{pmatrix} a & b \\ \overline{b} & c\end{pmatrix}$ positive?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-calculus, positive-definite

When is the matrix $\begin{pmatrix} a & b \\ \overline{b} & c\end{pmatrix} \in M_2(\mathbb{C})$ positive?

I showed that it is necessary that $a,c \ge 0$ and that the determinant is positive. I now want to show the converse. So my question boils down to:

If $a,c \ge 0$ and $ac \ge |b|^2$, are the eigenvalues of $\begin{pmatrix} a & b \\ \overline{b} & c\end{pmatrix} \in M_2(\mathbb{C})$ all positive?

Comment: What are your ideas?

Comment: @SamuelM.A.Luque I tried to work with the definition of eigenvalue and solve some system of equations but it didn't quite work out.

Comment: Are you claiming $a=b=c=0$ is positive?

Comment: @user10354138 I am yes. Positive matrix means positive eigenvalues and self-adjoint, which is clearly satisfied in your case.

Comment: I think the most standard terminology for a self-adjoint matrix with nonnegative eigenvalues would be "positive semidefinite" as opposed to just "positive", but different authors do sometimes use different wording.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The characteristic equation is
$$(\lambda - a)(\lambda - c) - |b|^2 = 0$$
or equivalently
$$\lambda^2 - (a+c)\lambda + ac - |b|^2 = 0$$
The solutions are given by the quadratic formula:
$$\lambda = \frac{1}{2}\left((a+c) \pm \sqrt{(a+c)^2 + 4|b|^2 - 4ac}\right)$$
which simplifies to
$$\lambda = \frac{1}{2}\left((a+c) \pm \sqrt{(a-c)^2 + 4|b|^2}\right)$$
from which it's clear that the expression inside the square root is nonnegative. This is expected since the eigenvalues of a self-adjoint matrix are real.

Both roots will be nonnegative if and only if
$$(a+c) \geq \sqrt{(a-c)^2 + 4|b|^2}$$
Since the RHS is nonnegative, the LHS $a+c$ must also be nonnegative, and in that case we can square both sides to get the equivalent inequality
$$(a+c)^2 \geq (a-c)^2 + 4|b|^2$$
which simplifies to
$$ac \geq |b|^2$$
So to summarize, the conditions are

- $a+c \geq 0$
- $ac \geq |b|^2$

which are equivalent your stated conditions $a,c \geq 0$ and $ac \geq |b|^2$.

Comment: The algebra involving the quadratic formula seems to be overkill here -- from $(\lambda - a)(\lambda - c) - |b|^2$ we can immediately see that we're looking at a parabola that opens upwards and has its apex halfway between $\lambda=a$ and $\lambda=c$. Such a function has two positive roots if (1) the axis is to the right of the $\lambda=0$ and (2) the function value at $0$ is positive. So we get $\frac{a+c}2 > 0$ and $ac-|b|^2>0$ right away.

Comment: @Troposphere That's a nice observation. I'll leave my answer as is with the quadratic formula and algebra (which isn't too bad) since it shows how to solve it if one doesn't spot the shortcut you observe. But you might want to post that as an answer! Btw, an even shorter answer but one that requires knowing a few things: the determinant is the product of the eigenvalues and the trace is the sum of the eigenvalues; both of these need to be nonnegative and that immediately gives us the same answer.